# journalctl entries are logged using the same time, in 5minute intervals

Tags: linux, logging, services, time, journalctl

I have a service which queries a database every second and print out results to console. When I look at journalctl I get a couple hundred lines that all have the same timestamp, and then the next couple hundred all have the same timestamp again just about 5m ahead of the previous. So I would have a couple hundred lines at 12:00:00pm, then the next block of couple hundred would be 12:04:58 and so on and so forth. Could anyone explain the reasoning for this?

Comment: Most likely the service doesn't flush its output so it's buffered. The buffer flushes when full.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for suggestion, don't know much about that but at least I have something to Google!